# How do I to create a copy of a custom object or collection?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a custom collection - let's call it `colParentA` - and it contains a number of collections called `colChild`.  I want to create a function that creates a new collection, `colParentB` that has all of the properties and contains the same children as `colParentA`.  The user can then modify the few properties of `colParentB` that they need to, rather than having to redefine ones that are the same as `colParentA`.

`colParentB` should also contain new instances of `colChild` that are copies of those found in `colParentA.

I can't just do this right?

```
set colParentB = colParentA

colParentB.Name = "Copy of " & colParentA.Name
```

Because this just makes `colParentB` point to `colParentA` and changes the properties of `colParentA` as well right?

I'm confused. Thanks for you help in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct in your suspicions - all you are assigning is pointers, so it'll just reference the same instance of the object with a different name.

You're probably going to need to create Clone functions on your colParent and colChild classes. That way colChild.Clone can do a memberwise clone and return a brand new object with the same properties, and colParent can create a new collection with the cloned colChild objects.

Be careful though, as if any of the properies of colParent or colChild are references to object then those may need to be cloned to to avoid you updating values you don't mean to.

Possible functions would be (note that I'm supposing the colChild contains a number of instances of a class clsContent - that'll need changing):

colParent.Clone:

```
Public Function Clone() as colParent
  'Start a new parent collection
  dim parent as colParent
  set parent = new colParent

  'Populate the new collection with clones of the originals contents
  dim child as colChild
  for each child in Me
    parent.Add(child.Clone)
  next

  set Clone = parent
End Function
```

colChild.clone:

```
Public Function Clone() as colChild
  'Start a new parent collection
  dim child as colChild
  set child = new colChild

  'Populate the new collection with clones of the originals contents
  dim content as clsContent
  for each content in Me
    child.Add(content.Clone)
  next

  set Clone = child
End Function
```

clsContent.Clone:

```
   Public Function Clone() as clsContent
      'Start a new parent collection
      dim content as clsContent
      set child = new clsContent

      child.Property1 = me.Property1
      child.Property2 = me.Property2
      ...

      set Clone = content
    End Function
```

Please excuse any bugs or typos - I don't have a dev env handy, so I'm writing straight into the text box!

Comment: Can you provide som esample code to get me pointed in the right direction? do I call the colChild.Clone method from within the colParent.Clone method? I'm just don't know how to go about creating these clone methods.

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm but rather than dimming a local parent and child in their respective clone methods I just `Set Clone = new colParent`.