# Problems Copying Custom Class

Tags: vba, class, oop, excel

Similar question to [How do I to create a copy of a custom object or collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226147/how-do-i-to-create-a-copy-of-a-custom-object-or-collection), but I can't get the solution to work for me. I have 3 related custom classes and having problems copying values from one instance of a class to another. I created Clone methods in each class to specifically create new instances to avoid multiple variables simply pointing to the same object. Here are my classes

class_stat:

```
Public value As Double
Public name As String
Public flagged As Boolean
Public category_name As String

Public Function Clone_Stat() As class_stat
    Dim stat As class_stat
    Set stat = New class_stat
    stat.name = Me.name
    stat.category_name = Me.category_name
    stat.flagged = Me.flagged
    stat.value = Me.value
    Set Clone_Stat = stat
End Function
```

class_cat:

```
Public name As String
Public stats As Collection
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set stats = New Collection 
End Sub

Private Function AddStat(ByRef stat As class_stat)
    stats.Add stat
End Function

Public Function Clone_Cat() As class_category
    Dim cat As class_category
    Set cat = New class_category
    'Copy the cat name
    cat.name = Me.name
    Dim stat As class_stat

    'Copy all the stats
    For Each stat In Me.stats
        cat.stats.Add (stat.Clone_Stat)
    Next stat
    Set Clone_Cat = cat
End Function
```

class_user:

```
Public username As String
Public name As String
Public categories As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
 Set categories = New Collection
End Sub

Private Function AddCategory(ByRef category As class_category)
    categories.Add category
End Function

Public Function Clone_User() As class_User
    Dim user As class_User
    Set user = New class_User
    Dim cat As class_category

    'Set values
    user.name = Me.name
    user.username = Me.username

    'Copy over the categories
    For Each cat In Me.categories
        user.categories.Add (cat.Clone)
    Next cat
    Set Clone_User = user
End Function
```

I'm able to copy one instance a class to another like this:

```
Dim temp_cat As class_category
Set temp_cat = New class_category
Dim temp_cat1 As class_category
Set temp_cat1 = New class_category
temp_cat1.name = "cat name"
Set temp_cat = temp_cat1.Clone_Cat
temp_cat.name = "cat name" 'Resets temp_cat name without affecting temp_cat1
```

However when I add a class_stat to class_category and try to copy it throws an error.

```
Dim temp_stat1 As class_stat
Set temp_stat1 = New class_stat
Dim temp_stat As class_stat
Set temp_stat = New class_stat

Dim temp_cat as class_category
Set temp_cat = New class_category
Dim temp_cat1 As class_category
Set temp_cat1 = New class_category

'Clone some stats fine - this works
temp_stat1.name = "stat name"
Set temp_stat = temp_stat1.Clone_Stat
temp_stat1.name = "stat1 name"

'Clone a cat with no stats - works
temp_cat1.name = "cat name"
Set temp_cat = temp_cat1.Clone_Cat
temp_cat1.name = "cat1 name"

'Try and add stats to temp_cat1 and clone and then it fails
Call temp_cat1.stats.Add(temp_stat.Clone_Stat) 'this works

Dim cloned_cat As class_category
Set cloned_cat = New class_category
Set cloned_cat = temp_cat1.Clone_Cat
```

The last line above throws the "Object doesn't support this property or method error." When I step through the debug it throws it after getting to the end of the Clone_Stat function. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything in this code that would initialize or assign to the `temp_stat` object.  Have you done that?

Comment: Yes, `temp_stat` was initialized just left it off my post accidentally. Added it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run this procedure:

```
Sub TestClones()

Dim temp_cat As class_category
Set temp_cat = New class_category
Dim temp_cat1 As class_category
Set temp_cat1 = New class_category
Dim temp_stat1 As class_stat
Set temp_stat1 = New class_stat
Dim temp_stat As class_stat
Set temp_stat = New class_stat
'Clone some stats fine - this works
temp_stat1.name = "stat name"
Set temp_stat = temp_stat1.Clone_Stat
temp_stat1.name = "stat1 name"

'Clone a cat with no stats - works
temp_cat1.name = "cat name"
Set temp_cat = temp_cat1.Clone_Cat
temp_cat1.name = "cat1 name"

'Try and add stats to temp_cat1 and clone and then it fails
Call temp_cat1.stats.Add(temp_stat.Clone_Stat) 'this works

Dim cloned_cat As class_category
Set cloned_cat = New class_category
Set cloned_cat = temp_cat1.Clone_Cat()

End Sub
```

I get the same error you do.

**Why the error?**

There is no default property for this collection, and when you put the parentheses around it, it is attempting to *evaluate* that expression, which raises the error.

**Resolution**

Remove the parentheses from this line:

```
cat.stats.Add (stat.Clone_Stat)
```

So  that you end up with this instead

```
cat.stats.Add stat.Clone_Stat
```

I also notice that in your `Clone_User` you have a mistake -- perhaps it is a typo but you do not have a `.Clone` method and I think this should be like so for the same reason:

```
user.categories.Add cat.Clone_Cat
```

Comment: Ahh vba syntax gets me again! Exactly what I needed and even caught a typo I hadn't noticed yet. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I didn't catch the typo I used the Debug | Compile option to do that :)